# How to increase the Fields of input in Firebase Leaderboard

Tags: firebase, leaderboard, hitcounter

Go to http://goo.gl/I4XLKF (Link to my jsfiddle workout)

Here I have tried to increase the input fields/option for Firebase LeaderBoard (https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/leaderboard), But it is Not working.

I have defined 3 Inputs/Firebase elements

- name  - this element/child is for the name of website
- AlternateURL - this element/child is for the URL of website
- Score - this element/child is for setting priority to the URL by entering numerical values.

I am using this LeaderBoard script to allow my users to sumbit alternate url for the various apps.

Comment: Instead of working around the "links to a fiddle must be accompanied by code", I suggest you include the relevant portion of your code in the question. Otherwise, this question will be closed as missing a SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this section, you only need to use the name field to reference the row and not your alternateurl.

```
// Store a reference to the table row so we can get it again later.
htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.name()] = newScoreRow;
htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.AlternateURL()] = newScoreRow;
```

get rid of the last line.

Unless there is an error somewhere else, you've addressed the areas to change/add code (variable names are my version:

```
<input type="text" id="urlInput" placeholder="URL">
newScoreRow.append($("<td/>").text(scoreSnapshot.val().url));
var url1 = $("#urlInput").val();
userScoreRef.setWithPriority({ name:name, score:newScore, url:url1}, newScore);
```